# using a variable in mongodb update

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Using Meteor, I'm trying to perform an update like the following:

```
Items.update(Session.get('selectedItem'), {'$set': {'directions.0.name': area.value}})
```

But I'm struggling with how to set the array index of directions dynamically, with something like this:

```
var index = //a value determined dynamically
Items.update(Session.get('selectedItem'), {'$set': {'directions[index]name': area.value}})
```

This doesn't work because [index] is wrapped in a string. I also tried to form a custom string, like this:

```
var string = 'directions.'+itemIndex+'.name'
Items.update(Session.get('selectedItem'), {'$set': {string: area.value}})
```

But that doesn't work. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need to build up your `$set` object programmatically:

```
var setModifier = { $set: {} };
setModifier.$set['directions.' + index + '.name'] = area.value;
Items.update(Session.get('selectedItem'), setModifier);
```

**Update**

If your JavaScript environment supports [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) (e.g. node.js 4+), you can do this in one step:

```
Items.update(Session.get('selectedItem'), { $set: {
    ['directions.' + index + '.name']: area.value
}});
```

Comment: Thanks..this may seem simple to some, but I am just learning mongodb.