# mongdb/nodejs: using variables in $inc doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following that i entered into the mongo terminal and it works great

```
db.cars.update({'_id':'FordXdfg'},{$inc :{'attribs.0.totl':1}})
```

which basically updates an array using dot notation, the 0 is the index of the array.

this does work. but transferring it to node my 0 comes from a variable.

so i tried

var carIndex = 3;

```
 cars.update({'_id':'FordXdfg'},{$inc :{'attribs.' + carIndex + '.totl':1}}, function (err, callback) ................)
```

seems to be invalid javascript, if i replace my carIndex with 3 then it works i.e.

```
 cars.update({'_id':'FordXdfg'},{$inc :{'attribs.3.totl':1}}, function (err, callback) ................)
```

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: `'attribs["' + carIndex + '"].totl'`

Comment: @adeneo not gonna work...

Comment: possible duplicate of [using a variable in mongodb update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393351/using-a-variable-in-mongodb-update)

Comment: @adeneo yes that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using that style of object initialization in JavaScript, property names must be string literals. When using the object initialization syntax, property names can not be constructed at run time in code. For example, you can only use literals like:

```
{
    "name": "Martin"
    "location": "Earth"
    "value": 1234
}
```

You **cannot** do this:

```
var propName = "name";
var obj = {
   propName: "Martin";
};
```

While it syntactically appears to work, you'll end up with an object that looks like:

```
{ 
    propName: "Martin"
}
```

Again, that's because only literal values are accepted when constructing an object using the shortened syntax. It will not interpret variable values.

There are two other options for setting properties of a JavaScript object, either through simple dot-notation:

```
obj.name = "Martin";
```

Or, you can use bracket notation:

```
obj["name"] = "Martin";
```

As objects in JavaScript act like associative arrays in that you can define new properties/keys at runtime each with a value, either syntax above works, and both result in the same underlying storage (and can be used interchangeably).

So, you'll need to construct the `$inc` syntax separately using the other technique for setting object property values in JavaScript:

```
var inc = {};
inc["attribs." + carIndx + ".totl"] = 1;
```

Then use that inside of your update:

```
{ $inc: inc }
```

Comment: thats great! any chance you can explain why it works ? the actually format seems really strange but sure enough the array = > var carIndx =4;
> var inc = {};
> inc["attribs." + carIndx + ".totl"] = 1;
1
> inc
{ "attribs.4.totl" : 1 }

Comment: Added a bunch of explanation.