# Update Mongo array: remove dynamic key

Tags: mongodb

Mongo newb. I'm trying to remove a tag based on the key which is an ObjectID:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("53ccff9bbb25567911f208a8"),

  "tags": {
    "53ccff9bbb25567911f208a4": "tag1",
    "53ccff9bbb25567911f208a5": "tag2",
    "53ccff9bbb25567911f208a6": "tag3"
  }
}
```

I think I know how to remove it from the array in javascript and update the document, but I'm trying to do this within a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `$unset`:

```
collection.update(
    {"_id": ObjectId("53ccff9bbb25567911f208a8")},
    {"$unset": {"tags.53ccff9bbb25567911f208a6": ""}}
)
```

This will remove the `"53ccff9bbb25567911f208a6": "tag3"` entry from `tags`.

More info at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/#up._S_unset

Comment: The issue I'm having is adding the ObjectID: {"$unset": {"tags."+tag: ""}} doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Stephane See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393351/using-a-variable-in-mongodb-update/12393480#12393480

Comment: @Stephane We can't help you further without seeing your actual code.