# How to let an admin change user properties in Meteor?

Tags: database, meteor, collections

Are there any special hoops one has to jump through when modifying user objects in Meteor?  I have no problem changing other collections but the users are strangely and persistently resistant to the many suggestions I have found.

I can see that there are some user attributes such as profile that are published and presumably quite easy to change.  I need more control over the access so just bunging my data into user.profile won't do. At the moment I'm trying to give users a grant table, so that for example I can write:

```
var user = Meteor.users.findOne();
var may_eat_popcorn = user.grants.popcorn;
```

This works:

```
$ meteor shell
// First check that the user is not allowed to eat popcorn:
> Meteor.users.findOne({_id:"iCTnpqwCR6jj9xxxx"});
  ....
  grants: { popcorn: false } }
// Give the non-gender specific entity access to popcorn:
> Meteor.users.update({_id:"iCTnpqwCR6jj9xxxx"},{$set:{"grants.popcorn":true}}, function(err,res){console.log("grant:",err,res);});
> Meteor.users.findOne({_id:"iCTnpqwCR6jj9xxxx"});
  ....
  grants: { popcorn: true } }
// Hooray.
```

This doesn't, even though equivalent code works fine with other collections:

```
Meteor.methods(
{ User_grant_popcorn: function(userId, granted){
            // authentication.  Then:
            var grants = {"grants.popcorn": granted};
            console.log(userId,grants);
            Meteor.users.update({_id:userId},{$set:grants}, function(err,res){console.log("grant:",err,res);});
            // This callback prints that there is no error, yet the database doesn't change on the server.
    }
});
// On the client the admin picks the target user and sets their degree of pop:
Meteor.call('User_grant_popcorn', user._id, false);
```

Do you know how user is different?  More importantly, how can I debug issues like this?  Winning means getting awesome things done fast.  That's meteor's promise. If debugging takes this long the advantage is lost.

Many thanks, Max

Comment: You need to create your `$set` programmatically - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393351/using-a-variable-in-mongodb-update

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically create `$set`

```
Meteor.methods({

  User_grant_popcorn: function(userId, granted) {
    // authentication.  Then:
    var grants = {
      "grants.popcorn": granted
    };

    var setHash = {
      $set: grants
    };

    console.log(userId, grants);

    Meteor.users.update({_id: userId}, setHash, function(err, res) {
      console.log("grant:", err, res);
    });
    // This callback prints that there is no error, yet the database doesn't change on the server.
  }

});
```

Comment: I actually already do that.  I trimmed that out here to make the question as simple as possible.  Regardless of whether the grants are set programmatically or as a once-off this has no effect if called from the client side.