# I want to remove the property inside a object in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, object

I have this bson doc in a collection. I want to remove a key based on dynamic value.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("53ccff9bbb25567911f208a2"),
  "image": {
    "image1": "5213423424234.jpg",
    "image2": "5213423424235.jpg",
    "image3": "5213423424236.jpg"
  }
}
```

In request I will get "image1"

```
temp/5bb3685b663c6f001d14c5da/dl/image1
```

I saved the key in a variable

```
let keyid = req.params.k_id
```

If I call the key directly, this works.

```
  let qry = {
    _id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.p_id)
  }
  let update = {
    $unset: {
      "image.image1": ""
    }
  }

  db.inventory.findAndModify({
      query: qry,
      update: update,
      safe: true
    }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).json({
            "success": false,
            "error": err
          })
          return
        }

        res.status(200).json({
          "success": true,
          "message": "Deleted image key"
        })
        return
    })
```

But since the key is dynamic, I am not able to find the solution with various possibilities

```
// Try1
    $unset: {
      'image.' + keyid: ""
    },
// Try2
    $unset: {
      `image.${keyid}`: ""
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the update obj like this

```
let update = {}
update["$unset"] = {};
update["$unset"]['image.' + keyid] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to build up your $unset object programmatically:

This question was answered here: [using a variable in mongodb update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393351/using-a-variable-in-mongodb-update/12393480#12393480)