# Use a variable in the name of a variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I was using quick.db, I used to do this :

```js
const table = new require('quick.db').table('table') // quick.db table
let guildID = msg.guild.id // snowflake generated by Discord; let's say it's equal to '1234567890'

table.set(`${guildID}.name`, `Cool Name`) // here, the variable name changes in function of guildID : so, to get 'Cool Name', I would have to look for '1234567890.name'.
```

And I am trying to do the same thing on mongoDB. In my view, it's a lot better and more complete than quick.db, but I still can't find how to do the same thing on mongo.

I guess that this is probably not possible, but I'd like to know if you have an idea about how I could replace this to easily get infos about a guild with its corresponding guildID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to a comment that sent me to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393351/using-a-variable-in-mongodb-update).

Even through with this method I can't create a value whose name is dependent of a variable directly as a field of the document, I can create one inside an object (the objects are selected with their names as strings, that's why I can insert a variable in that string)

```js
collection.updateOne({id: "123"}, {$set: { ["object."+guildID+".name"]: "Cool Name" }}
```

Then, `"Cool Name"` can be found with:

```js
collection.find({id: "123"}, {"object.1234567890.name": 1}) // note: I don't remember how to get a specific field of a document, please correct me or delete this note if you know what's correct
```